# DRF + Nested-Routers - "QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, drf-nested-routers

Using DRF and DRF-nested-routers

Here's my code:

```
class MemberViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = GroupMember.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupMembersSerializer


    def create(self, request, group_pk=None):
        queryset = self.queryset.all()
        serializer = GroupMembersSerializer(queryset)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

But once a new Member is posted the error "QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user' comes up

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

To serialize a queryset (or list of objects) you need to pass `many=True`

```
serializer = GroupMembersSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

Otherwise it thinks you want to serialize a single `GroupMember` instance, which is why it tried to access the `user` attribute on it

Answer (score 1):

If isn't too late in your development and you have the choice, you may want to check out https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions. It does routers nesting in a non-intrusive manner - you won't be required to overwrite the viewsets basic methods.

I've learned form the past that drf-nested-routers will interfere with the underlying viewset methods which enable pagination and filtering on your class:

- get_queryset
- get_serializer_class
- get_serializer
- get_object

In my opinion affects too much from the Viewset design and functionality for what it offers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out!